# Array for visited co-ordinates in c++

Tags: c++, visited

I am working on a game which has a map of 16000 X 9000 units, If I am at any point X,Y on map, I can see upto a radius of 2000 units. I wanted something from which I could manage whether I've visited a particular region or not. The main question is Should I take an array of bools? It will be too large bool visited[16000*9000]. So wanted advise, thanks. I am new to stackoverflow, sorry if I am not to the point.

Comment: It will be just `144 MB`. If you're very concerned, you may use `vector<vector<bool>>` and due to optimizations it will probably require just `18 MB`.

Comment: 18MB is not much these days

Comment: `16000*9000` is approximately `137 * 2^20`, so it shouldn't be too large to store on RAM of today's typical personal computers?

Comment: @MikeCAT `16000*9000` is 144,000,000.  At 1byte per element that is 144 MB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean not xor but pow by `^`. Also please assume `^` has higher precedence than `*` here.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm sorry, I read your comment wrong.  I though you said it would be to big.  I saw *should* instead of *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would indeed be inefficient to use an array of `bool` types. Mainly because the size of a `bool` in C++ can be luxuriously big. (On my platform, it's 8 bits long which means that 7 bits of it are not used.) The C++ standard does not specify the value of `sizeof(bool)`.

Do consider using a `std::vector<bool>` instead: this is an explicit specialisation of `std::vector` and the C++ standard **guarantees** this is tightly packed: i.e. there is no wasted space. You *might* need a `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` if you have difficultly acquiring one contiguous block of memory. This all said, some folk dislike the `bool` vector specialisation with a vengeance so do consider this carefully before diving in. (There is a movement to consider scheduling it for deprecation!)

Or you could *lump* areas of your graph together yourself into a set of integral types such as `unsigned`.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what a vector is yet, even though if I do, Will I need to push_back each and every co-ordinate of the map?

Comment: Not as such. You just need to allocate the necessary space in the vector, and initialise to "unvisited". See `std::vector<bool>::resize`.

Comment: It's 8bits not bytes

Answer (score 1):

If you need the discovered region to be circular (which your use of 'radius' implies) you have to use this huge arry, yes.

If it does not have to be a perfect circle, then you can simply downsample: say you use a roughness of 10 blocks - then you only need an array of 1600x90 size - a factor 100 reduction compared to the perfect circle.